# Extol the virtues antonym

Tags: word-choice, antonyms

When somebody wants to enthusiastically praise something or someone a common phrase used is to *"extol the virtues of ..."*".

There are two antonym senses I am after

1. A passionate critique of the problems with something
2. A sober discussion of the negative aspects of something

What phrases are similar to *"extol the virtues ..."* when applied to the above two negative cases.

The first sense being an equally passionate critique of something/someone and the second being a more dispassionate discussion, more sober.

It seems to me these senses are required if one wants to say something like

*In relation to x I can at length extol its virtues and provide a cautionary note as to its disadvantages. Passionate critiques can also be found in many sources.*

Comment: 2) to pinpoint the flaws 1) to castigate its imperfections

Comment: I have read "enumerate the vices" on a couple of occasions.

Comment: For (1) you can say ***launch fierce/harsh/scathing criticism***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Rail against"** is a near antonym, since it means, as a phrase, to negatively discuss something at length. It's used for unthinking attacks, sometimes, but that's not the proper meaning. It *does*, however, convey emotion.

[Webster's](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/Rail)

> "X railed against y, discussing their parentage and mental status in great detail along with a list of charges against their politics."

A single word could be **"condemn"** for the idea of arguing against a thing, or **"dismiss"** if the opposite of praising *and* detail is desired.

If you want to convey someone attacking a position with words, combative or medical language is often employed. "He attacked the opposing council with surgical precision, destroying every point made." *et cetera*.

**Decry** would be good for denoting a condemnation.

A fair critique would offer advantages and disadvantages, both. In some cases, that could avoid needing to explain the balance.

When attempting to explain a discussion of an idea as fair and dispassionate, I usually modify "critique", "argue", "argument", "discuss", or "reasons" rather than use something like "consider/expound the disadvantages", but that's a direction to go. These tend to be neutral, but that means you can apply these to advantages or to disadvantages:

- "Ennumerate" implies a certain emotional distance and at least an attempt at thoroughness. Literally means to number a thing.
- "Expound" denotes an explanation of a thing. If you expound the flaws, you, therefore, explain them.
- "Describe" or "discuss" can work if you want to mention why it has the traits that it does. "Consider" could serve, too.
- "Detail" as a verb, is probably the strongest neutral term for describing traits. "Detailing the faults" would clearly convey a completeness and, without other modification, implies reason.

As to terms to move from neutral to negative: *disadvantages, flaws, vices, problems, issues, penalty, demerit.*

*Results, consequences, effects* all remain neutral.

*Advantages, feature, virtue, merit, upshot, bonus* are positive.

Assemble as needed.

Comment: What a great answer!

Answer (score 2):

denounce

> to publicly state that someone or something is bad or wrong : to criticize (someone or something) harshly and publicly

condemn

> to declare to be reprehensible, wrong, or evil usually after
>   weighing evidence and without reservation

Answer (score 1):

In either case, I might start with the phrase "***offering some criticism(s)***".

> While admitting *x*'s many virtues, allow me to offer the following
>   criticisms:...

Answer (score 1):

You may use  ***[deprecate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deprecate)***:

> - to criticize or express disapproval of (someone or something)
>
>   - *He always deprecates my ​achievements.*

(M-W)